# React Native 0.63 generated podfile [!] The Podfile does not contain any dependencies

Tags: react-native, cocoapods, react-native-ios

I have built an app which is working on android fine. I have now got a MacBook Pro (M1) and am trying to build my RN app to iOS.

I ran `sudo gem install cocoapods`

I installed the packages at the root using `npm install`

`cd ios`

`pod init`

here is my podfile

```
# Uncomment the next line to define a global platform for your project
# platform :ios, '9.0'

target 'caffeind' do
  # Comment the next line if you don't want to use dynamic frameworks
  use_frameworks!

  # Pods for caffeind

  target 'caffeindTests' do
    inherit! :search_paths
    # Pods for testing
  end

end

target 'caffeind-tvOS' do
  # Comment the next line if you don't want to use dynamic frameworks
  use_frameworks!

  # Pods for caffeind-tvOS

  target 'caffeind-tvOSTests' do
    inherit! :search_paths
    # Pods for testing
  end

end
```

as you can see there are no pods where I expected more, so when I run `pod install` i receive the message and rightly so...

> Pod installation complete! There are 0 dependencies from the Podfile and 0 total pods installed.

> [!] The Podfile does not contain any dependencies.

however when I then go to build in my Xcode using caffeind.xcworkspace file, I receive the error

> 'React/RCTBridgeDelegate.h' file not found

there is some helpful advice here - https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/25838 but...

I cannot add React to the schemes and I do not see it in my Libraries folder in my project navigator. As the above error seems to be linked to the cocoapods dependency, I believe these issues are linked and whenever I try to manually add React pods to the podfiles there is always another dependency or pod that it needs.

This is my xCode directory

- caffeind

  - caffeind
  - Libraries - empty
  - Products
  - Frameworks
  - Resources
  - Pods
- pods
  -etc

versions:

- React Native - 0.63.2
- React Native cli - 4.14.0
- Ruby - 2.6.3p62 (2019-04-16 revision 67580) [universal.x86_64-darwin20]
- Cocoapods - 1.10.1
- Xcode - 12.4
- MacBook Pro - Big Sur - 11.2.3 - M1

Comment: did you pod install ?

Comment: Yes I ran pod install

Comment: You should rm -rf node_modules, npm i , ios folder pod deintegrate then pod install after that go to xcode project build clean then build again and should work

Comment: unfortunately I'm still getting the same

- no dependencies installed 
- 'React/RCTBridgeDelegate.h' file not found
- no 'React' in the Xcode Project Navigator > Libraries

Comment: same here.. please help